# Find the area of ​the shaded region.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Given, $MT=2$ and $AC=8$. Calculate the area of ​​the shaded region.

[image]
$\triangle BMT_(notable)\implies (a, 2a, a\sqrt5)\\
\therefore MT = 2, BT=4\\
\triangle ABF \sim \triangle MBT \implies k = \frac{MT}{BT }=\frac{1}{2} =\frac{AF}{BF}\therefore AF =2.2 = 4, BF = 2.4 = 8 \\
S\triangle AMC = S\triangle MCB$

Missing a detail,,,

**I managed to solve**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
$MT=2, BT = 4, BM = 2\sqrt5\\
\triangle AGC \sim \triangle MTB\\
\frac{GC}{TB}=\frac{AC}{MB}\\
\frac{GC}{4}=\frac{8}{2\sqrt5}\\
∴GC=\frac{16}{\sqrt5}\\
S_{\triangle MBC} =\frac{1}{2}.MB⋅GC=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\sqrt5 \cdot \frac{16}{\sqrt5}=16$

Comment: How do you know that $AF$ is twice $MT$?

Comment: But fortunately the answer is independent from the position of $A$, hence your answer gives the correct value.

Comment: The simplest way is that of choosing $A\equiv M$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Since the triangles $ABF$  e $BMT$ are similar and the similarity ratio is $1/2$ we will have $2MT = AF$

Comment: The similarity ratio is $MB/AB=MT/AF=BT/FB$, which could be any value and is different from $MT/BT$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca you're right...I fixed the solution